# How do I encrypt or hide pictures taken using a certain camera app from the phone's public gallery?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, permissions, camera

I am working on a simple camera app whose pictures should only be visible in the app that created the pictures. I am testing with Samsung galaxy phone running on android 12. My snippets are in kotlin
I want to save to a directory that does not get scanned for media. However, I think I might have a permission problem trying to access the data directory such as "`/data/user/0/com.example.demo.camerax/files/CameraXDemo/`".
Whenever I attempt to save pictures, I get the error "Failed to write destination file"

```
            // Mirror image when using the front camera
            isReversedHorizontal = lensFacing == CameraSelector.DEFAULT_FRONT_CAMERA
        }
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        // Options fot the output image file
        val outputOptions = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            val extn = "beg"
            val filename = System.currentTimeMillis()
            val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "$filename")
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, oDir)
            }

            val contentResolver = requireContext().contentResolver

            // Create the output uri
            val contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)

            OutputFileOptions.Builder(contentResolver, contentUri, contentValues)
        } else {
            File(oDir).mkdirs()
            val file = File(oDir, "${System.currentTimeMillis()}.jpg")

            OutputFileOptions.Builder(file)
        }.setMetadata(metadata).build()
```

This is the snippet that should create the directory above and save the pictures.
I have set my permissions in the Manifest file as follows

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
```

Android Marshmallow requires that the user will grant permission in order to make modifications. Here's how I implemented this

````
private val permissions = mutableListOf(
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    ).apply {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION)
        }
    }

    private val permissionRequest = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) { permissions ->
        if (permissions.all { it.value }) {
            onPermissionGranted()
        } else {
            view?.let { v ->
                Snackbar.make(v, R.string.message_no_permissions, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                    .setAction(R.string.label_ok) { ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(requireActivity()) }
                    .show()
            }
        }
    }```

Is there a better approach to hiding pictures taken
````

Comment: If you disguise your files as non-media using a proprietary file extension, would that hide them from general scanning, but allow you to find those (and only those) files?

Comment: You can use both getFilesDir() and getExternalFilesDir() and you do not need any permission to do so. Use those app specific directories.

Comment: And of course you will NOT use the mediastore to save your files as mediastore is all public.

Comment: @ThomasTimbul Yes that is an option. to change the File extension on image save

Comment: @blackapps. Thanks. I will do some modifications then

Comment: Changing extension of an image file is not possible on Android 11+ devices as Android will accept only image file extensions in public directories like Pictures and DCIM.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve hiding pictures taken by the camera app by creating a hidden directory done by adding a dot before the directory name. I eliminated the use of mediastore library totally. The function below did the trick.

```
private fun getOutputDirectory(): File{
        val mediaDir = externalMediaDirs.firstOrNull()?.let {mFile ->
            File(mFile, ".${resources.getString(R.string.app_name)}").apply {
                mkdirs()
            }
        }

        return if(mediaDir != null && mediaDir.exists())
            mediaDir else filesDir
    }
```